# One to Many join, if any values in the "Many" table column = 1 then set a flag in the "One" table = '1' where One.ID = Many.ID

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables. The "One Table" has  distinct unique LoadIDs and  a true/false flag (1 or 0). The  "Many Table" has multiple items and those multiple items belong to a single load. Also  each Item has a true or false flag.

I need to do a select where if any flags in the "Many Table"  are true for a particular LoadID, then I want to select the flag as true for the  single LoadID in the "One table "

The end result should be 1 single distinct record for each LoadID

Any hints on how to achieve this efficiently in a heavy transaction scenario?

My Query and result set so far

```
Select Distinct L.Hazmat AS L_Hazmat, "DM_Hazmat" =
CASE
WHEN L.Hazmat = 0 and I.Hazmat = 0 THEN 0
WHEN L.Hazmat = 0 and I.Hazmat = 1 THEN 1
ELSE L.Hazmat
END
FROM tblLoads L with (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblLoadItems I with (NOLOCK) ON L.LoadGuid = I.LoadGuid
WHERE L.LoadGuid = 'EB09E71B-82F0-41DB-BCBC-03896EE04789'
```

L_Hazmat    DM_Hazmat
   0               0
   0               1

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? BTW, you might want to look at this article before you litter your database with nolock hints everywhere. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
 Select "L_Hazmat" = L.Hazmat, 
        "DM_Hazmat" = 
             CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (
                  SELECT  1
                  FROM    tblLoadItems I with (NOLOCK) 
                  WHERE   I.Hazmat = 1
                     AND  L.LoadGuid = I.LoadGuid
                  )
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END
 FROM tblLoads L with (NOLOCK)
```

This will return you the value of `L.Hazmat` as well as a `1` if *any* value of `I.Hazmat` with the same `LoadGuid` value is `1`.  And it doesn't require grouping or a `DISTINCT`, which will probably make it perform better.